# Copy Editor badge problem?

Tags: support, edit-badges, askubuntu

I just got told I had the copy editor badge on Ask Ubuntu. However my gold badge count did not change so I became suspicious.

According to [Google's cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:I4ulnr3Dh3EJ:askubuntu.com/users/866/fluteflute+https://askubuntu.com/users/866/fluteflute&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk&source=www.google.co.uk) I had the Copy Editor badge ten days ago. This tallies with what I thought.

So why did I get notified for it again?

Answer (score 2):

Hover over the badge name in the cache page you linked. It says "edited 600 entries." The requirements for the badge were tweaked *five* days ago to modify the definition of a qualifying edit and change the number of edits required to 500. You probably lost the badge and then re-earned it, and got notified as a result of that. (Yes, according to waffles, this is a rare instance where badges were actually revoked.)